# How to sort iterable with Python without using stable sort?

Tags: python, python-3.x, sorting

So, I have an iterable in Input like this:

```
[4, 6, 2, 2, 6, 4, 4, 4]
```

And I want to sort it based on decreased frequency order. So that the result will be this:

```
[4, 4, 4, 4, 6, 6, 2, 2]
```

So what happened here is that, when an element has the same frequency of another one, they will be in the same order (6 appeared first so the 6 goes before the 2).

I tried to implement this mechanism using the sorted function but I have a big problem.

```
def frequency_sort(items):
    
    return sorted(items, key=lambda elem: sum([True for i in items if i == elem]), reverse=True)
```

I know this short way is difficult to read but it just sort the array using the key parameter to extract the frequency of a number. But, the output is this:

```
[4, 4, 4, 4, 6, 2, 2, 6]
```

As you can see the output is a little different from what it should be. And that happened (I think) because `sorted()` is a function that does a "stable sort" i.e. a sort that will keep the order as it is if there are same keys.

So what is happening here is like a strong stable sort. I want more like a soft-sort that will take into account the order but will put the same elements next to each other.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You could use [collections.Counter](https://docs.python.org/3/library/collections.html#collections.Counter) and use `most_common` that returns in descending order of frequency:

```
from collections import Counter


def frequency_sorted(lst):
    counts = Counter(lst)
    return [k for k, v in counts.most_common() for _ in range(v)]


result = frequency_sorted([4, 6, 2, 2, 6, 4, 4, 4])
print(result)
```

**Output**

```
[4, 4, 4, 4, 6, 6, 2, 2]
```

From the documentation on [most_common](https://docs.python.org/3/library/collections.html#collections.Counter.most_common):

> Return a list of the n most common elements and their counts from the
> most common to the least. If n is omitted or None, most_common()
> returns all elements in the counter. Elements with equal counts are
> ordered in the order first encountered

Comment: Worth noting that this assumes that whatever you are sorting is immutable - if you're sorting a mutable comparable (but *why*?) then this duplicates one copy of the comparable, rather than leaving all in.  But it's clean, clear, and generally what you want.  +1!

Comment: I understood how the Counter works but I'm struggling to get that for loop. Why there are two variables? I knew that whenever you had two variables cycling through different things in a for loop you should use the zip() function. Also, the second for loop is inside the first?

Comment: @TechMatt Yes the second for loop is inside the first basically the two values are the element (4 for example) and the count (for the case of 4 for 4).

Comment: @SeanVieira Then again, if the items are mutable, they're likely not hashable and thus this wouldn't work at all rather than silently duplicating.